# Powershell Studio 2018 - How to retrieve textbox values properly?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am having an issue with retrieving values from objects in Powershell Studio 2018 but my main issue is with the TextBox object. I have a wizard form that contains a textbox on step one. I would like to retrieve the output of that textbox in step two of the wizard. However, when I try to retrieve it by using:

```
$textboxname.Text
```

I receive the following output instead of the entered value:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Text. Text:
```

I have checked all of the documentation but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have also tried to use the .ToString property without any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear in your question but are you saving content of the textbox to a variable?

As an example this snippet works perfectly

```
$button1_Click={
#TODO: Place custom script here

[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($textbox1.text)
```

}

The above is copying to clipboard but similarly you can do that with a variable.

On the other hand if you're trying to read the value of textbox1 from a child form, assuming a multi form project, that won't work.

Let me know if this helps or if you can give us some more details I can try to reproduce the issue on my side but having a snippet of the code is not working for your would be beneficial.

Comment: This did it. I think I had the logic twisted around in my head. I was doing this with a Wizard and was trying to get the textbox text on step one (form1) to step two (form2). Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Glad you nailed it :-)